# HTML5 Local Storage not working in IE

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, internet-explorer-10

In IE 10, when I try to access window.localStorage it gives me the following error - "An internal error occurred in the Microsoft Internet extensions". I do not get the error in Chrome or Firefox. Does anyone have a clue as to why this is happening?

Comment: All extensions have been disabled -> Same error.

Comment: "Microsoft Internet extensions" in this context is referring to the WinINET library, whose cache containers the localStorage API is using. Try running Process Monitor and watch for Access Denied or similar failures.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/jarednova/jquery-total-storage/pull/6

Comment: @EricLaw Would you happen to know how to fix this?

Comment: If you're not on a corporate network where Group Policy might be blocking it, Click Tools > Internet Options > Advanced > Reset.... Choose the "All" option. If that doesn't help, you need to contact Product Support.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the error I ended up having to uninstall IE 10 (and in the process revert back to IE 9).